# How to add basic auth to a header on a WMS source in Mapbox

Tags: authentication, mapbox, basic-authentication, mapbox-gl-js, wms

I am using MapBox and am adding a WMS source pretty much identically to the code at this URL https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/

For convenience, the code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add a WMS source</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFyaWRhdGEiLCJhIjoiY2oxZXU2dzUwMDAwaDJxdGdpOGtoNWc2MyJ9.hs8kOWZetlwyMg6COnKwCg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
zoom: 8,
center: [-74.5447, 40.6892]
});
 
map.on('load', function () {
map.addSource('wms-test-source', {
'type': 'raster',
// use the tiles option to specify a WMS tile source URL
// https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/
'tiles': [
'https://img.nj.gov/imagerywms/Natural2015?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:3857&transparent=true&width=256&height=256&layers=Natural2015'
],
'tileSize': 256
});
map.addLayer(
{
'id': 'wms-test-layer',
'type': 'raster',
'source': 'wms-test-source',
'paint': {}
},
'aeroway-line'
);
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

The challenge that I have is that the WMS source I am getting the tiles from needs to have a username and password sent as Basic Auth in the header.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this using the Mapbox GL JS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `transformRequest` property to the map initialisation for this. The example in the Mapbox documentation is almost exactly your use case:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    center: [-122.420679, 37.772537],
    zoom: 13,
    style: style_object,
    hash: true,
    transformRequest: (url, resourceType)=> {
        if(resourceType === 'Source' && url.startsWith('http://myHost')) {
        return {
            url: url.replace('http', 'https'),
            headers: { 'my-custom-header': true},
            credentials: 'include'  // Include cookies for cross-origin requests
        }
    }
}
});
```

You will have to modify it slightly for your WMS scenario.

Comment: Hi Steve - that's really helpful - now I am getting this error:  "Access to fetch at 'MY WMS SERVER [REDACTED]' from origin 'https://localhost:44389' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'."  Is this on me to solve, or the WMS Server I am trying to connect to?

Comment: Sounds like a whole new question for you to write.

Comment: Dear @Steve Bennett, if you could solve your problem can you please share the transformRequest part of your code, of course without real token. I am having the very same problem and I couldn't solve it.